# Binance API get_aggregate_trades combination of optional parameters inavild

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I'd like to request aggregated trade data beginning at a certain timestamp until now

```
client.get_aggregate_trades(symbol = 'EURBUSD', startTime = 165605516493)
```

but i only get an Error:

> File "c:\Users\Pascal\Python Skripts\Binance\test.py", line 39, in 
> aggregate = client.get_aggregate_trades(symbol = ticker, startTime = 165605516493)
> File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 743, in get_aggregate_trades
> return self._get('aggTrades', data=params, version=self.PRIVATE_API_VERSION)
> File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
> return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
> return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 315, in _request
> return self._handle_response(self.response)
> File "C:\Users\Pascal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 324, in _handle_response
> raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
> binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1128): Combination of optional parameters invalid.

Even if i input all possible parameters (start and end time less than 1 hour), it still throws the same Error. What am i missing here?

Thank you a lot for helping.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I fixed it by adding an **"endTime"** parameter to the **"get_aggregate_trades"**.

```
client.get_aggregate_trades(symbol='BTCUSDT', startTime='1534130155000', endTime='1534130169000')
```